# Count to join with letter even when it's 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
wordFile = open('words.txt')
words = list(wordFile.read())
char = set(words)
chars = list(char)
chars.remove('\n')
for char in chars:
  count = words.count(char)
  if count > 1:
     print (char,'appears', count, 'time')
```

I want the code above to output the number of times the symbol appears even when the value is '1'.
Here is the current output of the code:

```
8 appears 3 times
0 appears 3 times
1 appears 3 times
2 appears 2 times
3 appears 6 times
4 appears 2 times
7 appears 2 times
) appears 2 times
* appears 4 times
+ appears 2 times
- appears 2 times
# appears 8 times
% appears 4 times
& appears 7 times
```

However, it is missing the values that appear '1' time (i.e.'\')
Here is what is stored inside words.txt

```
#+/084&"
#3*#%#+
8%203:
,1$&
!-*%
.#7&33&
#*#71%
&-&641'2
#))85
9&330*
```

So just to clarify the point of this is to output the freaquency that the symbol appears in the file. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `return true` answered your question;

You may want to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to find the frequencies.

```
>>> import collections
>>> with open('words.txt') as f:
    words = list(f.read())


>>> count = collections.Counter(words)
>>> del count['\n']
>>> for c, n in count.items():
    print('{} appears {} times'.format(c, n))

! appears 1 times
# appears 8 times
" appears 1 times
% appears 4 times
$ appears 1 times
....
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `if count > 1:` to `if count > 0:`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('words.txt') as wordFile :
    words = list(wordFile.read())
    char = set(words)
    chars = list(char)
    chars.remove('\n')
    for char in chars:
      count = words.count(char)
      print (char,'appears', count, 'time')
```

There's really no need for the `if` at all if you are going to print anything greater than 0.